# How can I get value from 2d array? - Python

Tags: python

I had a 2D array where every row has 2 elements:

```
R3 = [
    [[0, 4, 4, ...]
    [[0, 0, 0, ...]
    [[4, 0, 0, ...]
]
```

And this is the position of elements of the 2D array.

```
whereR3 = [
    [0, 1],
    [0, 2],
    [1, 4],
    [1, 34],
    [2, 0],
    [2, 5],
    [3, 8],
    [3, 9],
    [4, 12],
]
```

I want to do subtract the second element of a row from the first element, but the bottleneck is getting the value in a certain position from the 2D array. Here's what I've tried:

```
print(R3[0][1] - R3[0][2])
```

With this code, I can't calculate through every row and can't do it in a loop.

Comment: This is not an array, this is a *list*

Answer (score 1):

You can easily used nested for loops like this:

```
for list_ in R3:
        for number in list_:
            print(number - list_[1]) #if you know that every row has array of 2 elements
```

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga is this Right?

Answer (score 1):

Python indexes from 0, so you'll need to select positions 0 and 1 instead of 1 and 2. You can do that pretty easily in a `for` loop like this:

```
for row in whereR3:
    print(row[0] - row[1])
```

If you want a new list where each row has been collapsed to `row[0] - row[1]`, you can use a list comprehension:

```
collapsed_R3 = [row[0] - row[1] for row in whereR3]
```

When executed, `collapsed_R3` will be equal to:

```
[-1, -2, -3, -33, 2, -3, -5, -6, -8]
```

And to get a specific row's collapsed value (row 0, for example):

```
whereR3[0][0] - whereR3[0][1]
```

Which is equal to `-1`. The first slice (`[0]` on both sides) selects the row, and the second slice (`[0]` and `[1]`) are selecting the item within the row.

Comment: Maybe you didn't understand my question. It is my fault. What I mean is, how can I get a value in certain position(whereR3).

Comment: @yeonbinson: Sure, I've added that to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = [y- x for x,y in R3]
[1, 2, 3, 33, -2, 3, 5, 6, 8]
```